# Java Snake Game -- Redrawing a specifc drawString() method

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, awt, draw

**The problem:**

I've been creating a Snake game in Java and everything is working smoothly. The only problem I've having is displaying the score. Each time the snake "eats" an apple, the score increases by 10. Instead of displaying the current score, it simply writes over the present score without actually erasing it. When I attempt to erase the content before re-displaying, I get an error and nothing appears, other than my background colour.

I have other Graphics components, including a paint() that I do NOT want affected.

**My attempt (theoretical):**

I display the score using a Graphics object that calls
     drawString("Current score: " + currScore, 0, (Constants.TOTAL_HEIGHT + 15));

I figured I have to call a clearRect() method, which makes sense to me. Unfortunately, I get a NullPointerException at the line specifying clearRect().

I'm not using Graphics2D just so I can first be familiar with Graphics. If resolving this issue involves Graphics2D, I have no problem using it.

**My attempt (the method in question):**

```
public void displayScore(Graphics g) {
    //clearScore.clearRect(0, getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    //g.clearRect(0, getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.drawString("Current score: " + currHighScore, 0, (Constants.TOTAL_HEIGHT + 15));

}
```

In the code, clearScore is a Graphics object declared in the class outside of any methods. My reason for using this was to avoid affecting the other graphics. I attempted each of the clearRect() lines and both produced the same NullPointerException, which is why I have them commented out. 
(Constants.TOTAL_HEIGHT + 15) is responsible for assigning the Y-coordinate.

**The Error Message:**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.nmw.view.CanvasFrame.displayScore(CanvasFrame.java:149)
at com.nmw.view.CanvasFrame.drawAll(CanvasFrame.java:43)
at com.nmw.view.CanvasFrame.run(CanvasFrame.java:64)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

drawAll is where I call all of my methods that take in Graphics to draw a segment of the game.

Apologies for the lengthy question =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are likely trying to draw with a null Graphics object. This usually occurs if you are not drawing within the `paint(...)` method if AWT or `paintComponent(...)` if Swing. The solution,

- draw within one of those two methods (depending on the library you're using).
- Always call the super's method within your painting method.
- Or use a Label (AWT) or JLabel (Swing) to display the data.

To be blunt, your statement: `"I have other Graphics components, including a paint() that I do NOT want affected."` -- is an unrealistic requirement if this is an AWT project and if you don't want to use a Label.

And this statement:

> In the code, clearScore is a Graphics object declared in the class outside of any methods. My reason for using this was to avoid affecting the other graphics.

Is not how you should do drawing, ever. You're finding out now why. If you happen to get a Graphics context during the running of the program, use it to assign Graphics to your class field, and then try to use that class field, you'll often get the NPE like you're seeing because a Graphics object thus obtained is not long-lasting.

---

If you need more in-depth help, please post your actual assignment requirements and more code. In particular your drawing methods. Best would be to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> My Snake game is an independent project I've been doing to learn more about Graphics. I've only been using the AWT library, however, I'll try using a Label. Thank you for your response and explanation of why I got the NullPointerException

If this is for your own project and not a school assignment, then I think that you will want to avoid using AWT and instead use Swing. It is much more powerful and flexible than AWT. There really is no reason why you'd want to use AWT now adays.

Comment: My Snake game is an independent project I've been doing to learn more about Graphics. I've only been using the AWT library, however, I'll try using a Label. Thank you for your response and explanation of why I got the NullPointerException.

Comment: I'll use a JLabel and edit the text it contains. To set where I want to place the JLabel, I figured that I should use setBounds(x,y,width,height). Is that the ideal method to use to adjust the x and y or is there a more suitable technique?

Comment: @CuckoOooo: I make it a point to avoid ever calling `setBounds(...)` on anything and to instead let my layout managers place my components for me. In the long run, it makes it much easier to upgrade and enhance my program.